# How can I build Qt Application in Qt creator with static links on Windows with VS2008 runtime?

Tags: windows, qt, static, build, linkage

I have downloaded qt-win-opensource-4.7.0-vs2008.exe from nokia site and use it when I build my application. My application realy use VS2008 runtime not MinGW, but it has the dynamic linkage with QtCore4.dll and others Qt libs.
How can I create application with static linkage with qt libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must build a static version of Qt. See http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/deployment-windows.html